# Execute queries on Amazon Redshift using the AWS SDK for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have been following aws-sdk for javascript to execute sql queries on redshift cluster but haven't been able to connect.

Can someone guide me regarding module to use for redshift connection in javascript (except node-redshift) or share a skeleton code with proper parameter names?

Using @aws-sdk/client-redshift

```js
const RedShiftClient = new RedshiftClient({region:'us-west-2'});
const params = {
  ClusterIdentified:'clustername-xxx-aws.com',
  NodeType: 'nodetype',
  MasterUsername:'user',
  MasterPassword:'password',
  ClusterType:'clustertype'
};

const command = new AcceptReservedNodeExchangeCommand(params);
redshiftClient.send(command)
.then(res=>{
//dosomething
})
.catch(err=>{
console.log(err);
});
```

Receiving error :
2 validation errors found: Value null at 'targeReservedNodeOfferingId' failed to satisfy constraint. Member cannot be null. Value null at 'reserverNodeId' failed to satify constraint. Member cannot be null.

Comment: [According to this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_AcceptReservedNodeExchange.html) the two parameters mentioned in the error message are indeed not optional.

Answer (score 1):

To execute queries on Amazon Redshift using JavaScript, use [RedshiftDataClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-redshift-data/index.html) (not **RedShiftClient** ). There are examples in the previous link. This is part of the **AWS SDK for JavaScript v3**.

To use a **RedshiftDataClient** object to query data, you can use the following Amazon Redshift values:

- The name of the database (for example, dev)
- The name of the database user that you configured
- The name of the Amazon Redshift cluster (for example, redshift-cluster-1)

These values are used when creating an **ExecuteStatementCommand** as discussed here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-redshift-data/classes/executestatementcommand.html